# function .push keep replacing all elements same as last one in array

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm trying to make trails of moving objects by using vector history array in p5js.
but after push updated vector, all elements in this.history replaced as last one.

I've searched some question here but still can't understand.

```
let ppp = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let p = new Particle();
    ppp.push(p);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  for (let i = 0; i < ppp.length; i++) {
    ppp[i].display();
    ppp[i].update();
  }
}

function Particle() {
  this.pv = createVector(random(width), random(height));
  this.history = [];

  let rndV = p5.Vector.random2D(); 
  this.spdV = rndV.mult(random(1, 3));
  
  this.update = function() {
    this.pv.add(this.spdV);
    this.history.push(this.pv); // replace all vector element
    
    console.log(this.history);
  }
  
  this.display = function() {
    fill(30);
    ellipse(this.pv.x, this.pv.y, 30);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < this.history.length; i++) {
      let trail = this.history[i];
      ellipse(trail.x, trail.y, 10);
    }
  }
}
```

or if you think my approach isn't the best, I'll be happy to hear any suggestion^^

Thanks,

Comment: its because all of the elements in your array point to this.pv, so when you change this.pv they still point to the changed this.pv.  Rather create a new object and store that.  const a = new Vector(...); this.history.push(a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a bit misleading in javascript:

```
this.history.push(this.pv);
```

You're pushing a reference to the same `this.pv` pre-allocated vector

What you are trying to do is something like:

```
this.history.push(this.pv.copy());
```

Where you are allocating memory for a completely new `p5.Vector` object with the x,y coordinates copied from `this.pv` (using the [copy()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/copy) method)

Demo:

```js
let ppp = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let p = new Particle();
    ppp.push(p);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  for (let i = 0; i < ppp.length; i++) {
    ppp[i].display();
    ppp[i].update();
  }
}

function Particle() {
  this.pv = createVector(random(width), random(height));
  this.history = [];

  let rndV = p5.Vector.random2D(); 
  this.spdV = rndV.mult(random(1, 3));
  
  this.update = function() {
    this.pv.add(this.spdV);
    this.history.push(this.pv.copy()); // replace all vector element
    
    //console.log(this.history);
  }
  
  this.display = function() {
    fill(30);
    ellipse(this.pv.x, this.pv.y, 30);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < this.history.length; i++) {
      let trail = this.history[i];
      ellipse(trail.x, trail.y, 10);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Bare in mind as the sketch runs this will use more and more memory.

If simply need to render the trails and don't need the vector data for anything else you can simply render into a separate graphics layer (using [`createGraphics()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics)) immediately which will save memory on the long run:

```js
let ppp = [];
let trailsLayer;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  // make a new graphics layer for trails
  trailsLayer = createGraphics(400, 400);
  trailsLayer.noStroke();
  trailsLayer.fill(0);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let p = new Particle();
    ppp.push(p);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  // render the trails layer
  image(trailsLayer, 0, 0);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < ppp.length; i++) {
    ppp[i].display();
    ppp[i].update();
  }
}

function Particle() {
  this.pv = createVector(random(width), random(height));
  
  let rndV = p5.Vector.random2D(); 
  this.spdV = rndV.mult(random(1, 3));
  
  this.update = function() {
    this.pv.add(this.spdV);
    // render trails
    trailsLayer.ellipse(this.pv.x, this.pv.y, 10);
  }
  
  this.display = function() {
    fill(30);
    ellipse(this.pv.x, this.pv.y, 30);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.min.js"></script>
```

**Update** to fade trails you could try something like [Moving On Curves](https://processing.org/examples/movingoncurves.html) example. Notice `noStroke();` is called in `setup()` and

```
fill(0, 2);
rect(0, 0, width, height);
```

render a faded out (alpha=2) rectangle ?

You could do something similar:

```js
let ppp = [];
let trailsLayer;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(255);
  // make a new graphics layer for trails
  trailsLayer = createGraphics(400, 400);
  trailsLayer.noStroke();
  // set translucent fill for fade effect
  trailsLayer.fill(255, 25);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let p = new Particle();
    ppp.push(p);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  // fade out trail layer by rendering a faded rectangle each frame 
  trailsLayer.rect(0, 0, width, height);
  // render the trails layer
  image(trailsLayer, 0, 0);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < ppp.length; i++) {
    ppp[i].display();
    ppp[i].update();
  }
}

function Particle() {
  this.pv = createVector(random(width), random(height));
  
  let rndV = p5.Vector.random2D(); 
  this.spdV = rndV.mult(random(1, 3));
  
  this.update = function() {
    this.pv.add(this.spdV);
    // reset at bounds
    if(this.pv.x > width){
      this.pv.x = 0;
    }
    if(this.pv.y > height){
      this.pv.y = 0;
    }
    if(this.pv.x < 0){
      this.pv.x = width;
    }
    if(this.pv.y < 0){
      this.pv.y = height;
    }
    // render trails
    trailsLayer.push();
    trailsLayer.fill(0);
    trailsLayer.noStroke();
    trailsLayer.ellipse(this.pv.x, this.pv.y, 10);
    trailsLayer.pop();
  }
  
  this.display = function() {
    fill(30);
    ellipse(this.pv.x, this.pv.y, 30);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.min.js"></script>
```

For the sake of completeness here's a version using the `history` vector array, but limiting that to a set size and reusing vectors allocated once (instead making new ones continuously):

```js
let ppp = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  noStroke();
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let p = new Particle();
    ppp.push(p);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  for (let i = 0; i < ppp.length; i++) {
    ppp[i].display();
    ppp[i].update();
  }
}

function Particle() {
  this.pv = createVector(random(width), random(height));
  // limit number of history vectors
  this.historySize = 24;
  this.history = new Array(this.historySize);
  // pre-allocate all vectors
  for(let i = 0 ; i < this.historySize; i++){
      this.history[i] = this.pv.copy();
  }

  let rndV = p5.Vector.random2D(); 
  this.spdV = rndV.mult(random(1, 6));
  
  this.update = function() {
    this.pv.add(this.spdV);
    this.resetBounds();
    this.updateHistory();
  };
  
  this.updateHistory = function(){
    // shift values back to front by 1 (loop from last to 2nd index)
    for(let i = this.historySize -1; i > 0; i--){
      // copy previous to current values (re-using existing vectors)
      this.history[i].set(this.history[i-1].x, this.history[i-1].y);
    }
    // finally, update the first element
    this.history[0].set(this.pv.x, this.pv.y);
  };
  
  this.resetBounds = function(){
    // reset at bounds
    if(this.pv.x > width){
      this.pv.x = 0;
    }
    if(this.pv.y > height){
      this.pv.y = 0;
    }
    if(this.pv.x < 0){
      this.pv.x = width;
    }
    if(this.pv.y < 0){
      this.pv.y = height;
    }
  };
  
  this.display = function() {
    fill(30);
    ellipse(this.pv.x, this.pv.y, 30);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < this.historySize; i++) {
      let trail = this.history[i];
      // fade trails
      let alpha = map(i, 0, this.historySize -1, 192, 0);
      fill(30, alpha);
      ellipse(trail.x, trail.y, 10);
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks George! The reason why I put them into array is I want the trails to be smoothly fadeout. Do I still need to seperate canvases in this case? (I probably use splice to remove element when they reach opacity less than 0)

Comment: No worries, feel free to also vote up if it was helpful. I've provided hints on how to do computationally inexpensive trails above. The transparency will control the length of the trail to a certain degree.

Comment: I did already, but I'm new here so don't have right to vote to be marked.. (minimum 15 reputation is required) I'm almost there!